# How to instal Perl modules GD and GD::Polyline in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, perl, cpan

I am trying to start [Circos](http://www.circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/configuration/perl_and_modules/) in Debian but I get two missing modules

```
root@masi:/home/masi/circos-0.69# bin/circos -modules | grep missing
missing            GD
missing            GD::Polyline
```

Trying to install

```
root@masi:/home/masi/circos-0.69# cpan GD
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.49_01)
Reading '/root/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 18 Nov 2016 15:53:48 GMT
Running install for module 'GD'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.88)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.064)
Checksum for /root/.local/share/.cpan/sources/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz ok
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.13)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4414)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.142690)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150214)
CPAN: Module::Build loaded ok (v0.421)
Configuring L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz with Build.PL
**UNRECOVERABLE ERROR**
Could not find gdlib-config in the search path. Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
  LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
```

I also did `apt-get install libgd` and `cpan libgd` but does not help.

OS: Debian 8.5
Perl: 5.20
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libgd-perl
```

will install GD and GD::Polyline.